# Creating Static array in stored procedure in postgresql

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql, oop

I need to write below PHP code in stored procedure

```
$arrintArTriggerIds = array();

if( CApplicationStage::PRE_QUALIFICATION == $this->getAdo()->m_objApplication->getApplicationStageId() && CApplicationStatus::APPROVED == $this->getAdo()->m_objApplication->getApplicationStatusId() ) {

    $arrintArTriggerIds = array( CArTrigger::PRE_QUALIFICATION );

}
```

And I need to pass this `$arrintArTriggerIds` array to select query with where conditions.
This array may contain values like `ar_trigger_id IN (102, 103)` etc.

Please help me with this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: have tried this many times but still not working. Hence created this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using @ with variable name:

```
declare @MonthsSale table(monthnr int)
insert into @MonthsSale (monthnr) values (1)
insert into @MonthsSale (monthnr) values (2)
```

AND you can also get records like

```
SELECT month_id FROM @MonthsSale;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Got the answer by my own

```
pArTriggerIds := ARRAY[CArTrigger::PRE_QUALIFICATION];
```

worked perfect for me with `ar_trigger_id = ANY ( pArTriggerIds )`

Thanks